# How to check some condition every 1 sec in java until true

Tags: java, android

I need to check certain condition in java every 1 second until it is true.Once it is true, need to exit from it and proceed further.

Say a->b->c
check b every 1 sec until it is true, if it is true go to c.

Could someone suggest what is the best possible way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Try reading up on TimerTask.

Comment: Can i use like this while(!b) { try { Thread.sleep(1000) } catch catch(InterruptedException ie) {} ;}

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you need:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!condition)
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                else {
                    // do actions
                    condition = true;
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should take a look at the [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) classes. You can use them to schedule certain tasks to take place after a certain amount of time.

You need to extend the 'TimerTask' class and override the `run()` method. For example, you could do something like this:

Here's an example, which prints `Hello World` every 5 seconds: -

```
class CheckCondition extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       // if some condition is true
          // do something 
    }
 }
```

Used from another method, which checks your condition once every second (the function takes milliseconds):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

// timer.schedule(class, initial delay, interval in milliseconds)
timer.schedule(new CheckCondition(), 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is using the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)'s postDelayed() method:

```
// do something A

do {
    // Execute some code after 1 second has passed
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            // do something B
        } 
    }, 1000); 
}
while(condition);

// do something C
```